# How to infer the "correct" type of a null value at runtime?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a variable:

```
let v: string | null = null;
```

Is there any way, at runtime, to know the type that **v** "should" be? In other words:

```
console.log(typeof v) // -> object

// Anything like?:
console.log(correcttypeof v) // -> string
```

**Picked answer from [Kaya3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299000/kaya3)**

> Typescript's types are fully erased; they do not exist at runtime, so
> there is no way a correcttypeof function could work

Comment: Your code should result in `Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)`. Did you mean `let v: string | null = null;`?

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for pointing that out. I edited the question

Comment: Currently you are assigning v to null so typeof v is 'object" is expected. Once you assign v to string then you will get the correct type. So what is the expectation here?

Comment: I have a function that returns different classes based on the type of the provided parameter. This parameter is nullable. Is there a simple way to predict that the parameter with `null` value "should" be a of a certain type? (`string` in this exemple)

Comment: Typescript's types are fully erased; they do not exist at runtime, so there is no way a `correcttypeof` function could work. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure

Answer (score 0):

[Per spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#Description), `typeof null === 'object'`. Sad but `true`.

It's very simple to check for `null`s, though — you just check `v === null`. This is guaranteed to work (unlike `v === undefined`, which fails in some rare edge cases).

Here's a rundown of how you can reliably runtime-check for all the basic types in TypeScript (adjust per your use case):

```
const is = {
  null: (val: unknown): val is null =>
    val === null,

  undefined: (val: unknown): val is undefined =>
    typeof val === 'undefined',

  array: (val: unknown): val is any[] =>
    Array.isArray(val),

  object: (val: unknown): val is object =>
    typeof val === 'object' && !is.array(val) && !is.null(val),

  nan: (val: unknown): val is typeof NaN =>
    Number.isNaN(val),

  number: (val: unknown): val is number =>
    typeof val === 'number' && !is.nan(val),

  boolean: (val: unknown): val is boolean =>
    typeof val === 'boolean',

  string: (val: unknown): val is string =>
    typeof val === 'string',

  symbol: (val: unknown): val is symbol =>
    typeof val === 'symbol',

  bigint: (val: unknown): val is number =>
    typeof val === 'bigint',

  function: (val: unknown): val is Function =>
    typeof val === 'function',
}

// use like this
const val = Math.random() < .5
  ? ['foo']
  : () => alert('surprise!')

if (is.array(val)) {
  val.push('bar')
} else if (is.function(val)) {
  val()
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#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)